# How Do I Customise The Path Devise Uses For Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view, devise

I have some custom views for Devise's `SessionsController`. I am using scoped views so they are currently located at:

`app/views/users/sessions`

I need to move the views into a subfolder so that their new location will be:

`app/views/public/users/sessions`

I have specified the layout I would like Devise to use for these views in `application.rb` using:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "public/layouts/application"
end
```

But I see no way to specify the view path.

**How can prepend `public` to the path Devise uses to look up the views?**

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be possible without Overriding each controller and adding a view path using `prepend_view_path`:

```
module Public
  module Users
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      prepend_view_path 'app/views/public'
      layout "public/layouts/application"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**View Scoping**

I don't know whether this will help:

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
  ...
  config.scoped_views = true
```

This is what Devise says about it:

> Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first
>   check for `users/sessions/new`. It's turned off by default because
>   it's slower if you are using only default views.

I guess that means if you have a custom `sessions_controller` inside the `/public` directory, it will switch the settings to suit?

Here's the [documentation to support this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)

Comment: Thanks, but as I mention in my question I'm already using scoped views and that works fine. The question was how to prepend `public` to the scoped path.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find our the solution, tried something and it worked:

```
namespace :public, module: nil, path: '' do
    devise_for :users, path: ''
end
```

This will generate paths for example: /sign_in, /sign_out without any prefix, and uses the devise views from views/public/users directory